# Google Map Marker with Javascript Custom Precise Timer Using Performance.now()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, timer

I have 10 pins that have been added to my map:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: my_lat[i], lng: my_lat[i]}
    });
}
```

Now I would like to display these markers on the map at a very precise interval. 
Using setInterval and setTimeout generates errors between 0 and 4 miliseconds.

`performance.now()` seems to be very precise. The timer I built prints in the console the elapsed time with an error less than 1 milisecond. (Which is great!)

However, the problem is that the markers are drawn only at the end of the for loop, all at once. Is there a way to make sure I draw them one by one?

Here is the drawing code:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
      var t0 = performance.now();
      var dt = 0;

      while (dt<1000){
          dt = performance.now() - t0;
      }
      markers[i].setMap(map);
      console.log(dt);
}
```

Comment: You have to give the browser time to render the markers, currently it is busy running your loop.  that said, I think your "exact time interval" is not useful on a webpage (a person is not going to be able to see events that are milliseconds apart)

Comment: I need the events to be accurately calculated not displayed accurately. I would be happy if the pins have delay of a few miliseconds on display. But their position must be calculated based on precise timings.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. To use setTimeouts instead of for loop:

```
        var s = 0;
        setTimeout(function(){
          console.log("start " + performance.now());
          setTimeout(tim, 0);
        }, 1000);

        function tim(){
          var t0 = performance.now();
          var dt = 0;

          while (dt<interval[s]){
            dt = performance.now() - t0;
          }   
          markers[s].setMap(map);
          console.log(dt);
          s++;
          setTimeout(tim, 0);
        }
```